# write table in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get my data from R.
When I type: `write.table(c, "~/XXX/XXX.txt", sep="\t")`. I get something like this:

```
"x"
"1" 3011.5648786606
"2" 15654.1820393584
"3" 12368.7319176159
"4" 3055.2054987339
"5" 4590.9390484852
"6" 15472.0519755823
"7" 22142.4386253643
"8" 43684.1996516822
"9" 20931.0908837875
"10" 15165.4255765957
"11" 21790.7749747969
"12" 42362.7562956186
.............................
```

How to get rid of "x", "1", "2",...?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE` in `write.table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the arguments in `write.table` are by default `TRUE`.  Change it to `FALSE` and it should work

```
write.table(c, "~/XXX/XXX.txt", sep="\t", quote=FALSE, 
                          row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

NOTE: `c` is a function.  So, it is better to give object names that are not functions.